# Using Apache Benchmark to load the urls from a text file

Tags: apachebench

Need to test the performance of API's with variable parameters (x and y)

e.g. `http://myapiurl?x=1&y=2&z=6`
     `http://myapiurl?x=3&y=3&z=6`
     `http://myapiurl?x=5&y=2&z=6`
     ..........

now while bench marking I want to hit the urls randomly from a text file.

`$ ab -c 100 -c 500 urls.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Patch - `https://github.com/philipgloyne/apachebench-for-multi-url/blob/master/README.md`

`gcc -I /usr/include/apr-1.0 -I /usr/include/apache2 ab.c -o ab  -lm -lapr-1 -laprutil-1`

`ab -c 100 -v 4 -n 2000 -L urls.txt > results.txt`

This will load the target urls from text file.